# Add custom action to Django inline object on the admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an admin interface that has a blog post, with inline models which are previus versions of the post.

I'd like to add an action for each one of the previous version (A revert action, custom model method)

how should I go about doing that?
its kinda similar to ModelAction actions keyword, but I want it to be inside the model view, not the list view
and also its for each inline model, not for the parent model

would love some help.

**to make it clearer**

my previous_version class has a function named revert. all I want is that in my blog post's view in the admin panel by each previous version I'll have a link or button or something. and pressing it will call previous_version.revert.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the right thing to make this is Admin actions as described in documentation -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: Thats not what I'm looking for. django admin actions are for interacting with lists of objects (in my case that would be lists of blog posts). I want to have a button in the single blog post view. I actually did a small hack to do it by overriding the template but I was looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Blog ModelAdmin with action `revert`.

Overriding inline model template to add a button, like you said you already did is a good way to do it.

Just be sure to wrap created view within [admin_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) and allow only post requests.